# Microsoft hosted agent bought but pipeline still fails for timeout

Tags: azure-devops, agent, azure-devops-hosted-agent

Our customer purchased 1 microsoft hosted agent (parallel jobs) because our Yaml build pipeline took more than 60 mins to complete. It was purchased more than 24 hours ago but still our pipeline fails for timeout when 60 minutes have exceeded. Do I have to do something to change the pipeline other than simply run the build again? I think it should automatically recognize that it's not free agent anymore.

I can also see the correct agent is running the job from the devops.

Comment: ...what product are you talking about here? You've only tagged "agent".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was solved by adding timeout -parameter. If it's missing, it's gonna be 60 minutes.